# Request.Url has wrong port information

Tags: asp.net, http, azure, port, nancy

My web application is using Nancy, and is hosted in Asp.Net, in Azure.
In development, I am using IIS Express, and Azure's Compute Emulator.

In production, the homepage opens in `http://mydomain/test`
Debugging on my machine, the homepage opens in `http://127.0.0.1:81/test`
But, in my NancyModule, I'm getting:

```
Request.Url == http://127.0.0.1:82/test
```

Why 82? Maybe it has something to do with IIS Express showing its site on `http://127.255.0.0:82/` ?

Comment: You shouldn't be seeing this behavior. Could you provide a sample application that reproduces it? Thanks

Comment: I've copied my solution and stripped it down to only one NancyModule that only checks for Requst.Url. This is the only class left. No Bootstrapper, no nothing, and the same happens. The Azure definitions include my company private keys so I can't share a working application...

Comment: but it works if you run it locally? Could you perhaps bring this up on our user group (you'll find a link on nancyfx.org)?

Answer (score -2):

82 is the port that IIS is serving the app through.  Are you trying to do something with it?

Comment: I have some code that depends on the address, and I don't want to right seperate code for development and production. IIS Express is serving the app through the different address I wrote in the question - Nancy gives me the only its port and not its IP...

Comment: Not sure what the down vote was for, as you did not explain this in your original question.  in production, you are using a DNS that maps to an IP address with the port (ie, 82).  Clearly your server in production is using a different port then your debug host.  You can change what port you are using in either IIS or in your IDE.  But, you should really parse the string and remove the port because you never really can tell what port your IIS admin may assign you

Comment: All you're doing is pointing out something that the OP mentioned in their question, and asking an additional question for clarification.  This seems like it would be more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: Also, don't be so quick to assume that the OP was the downvoter - I cast the first downvote on this answer.

Comment: Jason - I did not down vote your answer, even with it not really helping, and as @jadarnel27 commented, it doesn't really qualify as an answer.
To further clarify: When debugging I see URL X in the browser. I want a piece of code that gets me X, not Y.