# Incorrect port in Request.URL with Azure Compute emulator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-express, azure-compute-emulator

I am using VS 2013. IIS 8.0 Express and Azure .NET SDK v2.2

With a simple WebAPI template project I am able to repro this. When I locally debug the project in the azure compute emulator, it starts up the web page in `https://127.0.0.1`. However, in the request, the URI comes up with port 444.

Is there any known fix / workaround for this bug?

I could find similar issues for others at following pages but their workarounds don't work for me.  Nothing in Request object or Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request object has the right URL. For e.g. if I try to open `https://127.0.0.1:444/`, I get "page not found" error.

1. [Wrong port number in mvc 4 windows Azure Request.Url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21062617/wrong-port-number-in-mvc-4-windows-azure-request-url)
2. [Request.Url has wrong port information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15163670/request-url-has-wrong-port-information)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After reading through [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cloud_solution_architect/archive/2014/11/08/vips-dips-and-pips-in-microsoft-azure.aspx), I think this might be by design. The request is associated with DIP rather than VIP since it is just been forwarded from the Load balancer.

However, this would still mean that I need to keep 443 unused for my service to function normally. My service redirect users to live login page and it has to provide the VIP domainname port as redirect url in order to get the request.

During local debugging, requests to url:port provided in Request.Url doesn't work. Overall this azure local debugging setup still looks like a mess.

Let me know if there is any other workaround/fix.